# Regex to match words with only non-special characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will match only words that do not contain special characters. In the following string:

one two:two three four five:five six

I want to match one, three, four, and six only. I want to exclude the two:two and five:five.
`/[a-zA-Z]+/` matches these words, but it also matches "two", "two", "five" and "five" since it just treats the ":" as a separator for another word.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you're using, so I'll provide a high-level overview of what to do.

Try splitting the string by whitespace (i.e., split by `/\s+/`), then match each part against `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could simply use `(?<=\s+|^)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s+|$)`.  Basically, it is your original expression, but requiring

- a prefix (i.e. `(?<=)`) of whitespace or the beginning of the string (i.e. `^`), and
- a suffix (i.e. `(?=)`) of whitespace or the end of the string (i.e. `$`).

That should do it for you!